# How to delete partial duplicate lines with AWK?

Tags: unix, awk, duplicate-data, lines

I have files with these kind of duplicate lines, where only the last field is different:

```
OST,0202000070,01-AUG-09,002735,6,0,0202000068,4520688,-1,0,0,0,0,0,55
ONE,0208076826,01-AUG-09,002332,316,3481.055935,0204330827,29150,200,0,0,0,0,0,5
ONE,0208076826,01-AUG-09,002332,316,3481.055935,0204330827,29150,200,0,0,0,0,0,55
OST,0202000068,01-AUG-09,003019,6,0,0202000071,4520690,-1,0,0,0,0,0,55
```

I need to remove the first occurrence of the line and leave the second one.

I've tried:

```
awk '!x[$0]++ {getline; print $0}' file.csv
```

but it's not working as intended, as it's also removing non duplicate lines.

Comment: Are your (near) duplicates always adjacent or can they be interspersed?

Comment: They are always adjacent, as they already are the result of another awk operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your near-duplicates are always adjacent, you can just compare to the previous entry and avoid creating a potentially huge associative array.

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{
    s = substr($0, 0, match($0, /,[^,]*$/))
    if (s != prev) {
        print prev0
    }
    prev = s
    prev0 = $0
} 
END {
    print $0
}
```

**Edit**: Changed the script so it prints the last one in a group of near-duplicates (no `tac` needed).

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{
    s = substr($0, 0, match($0, /,[^,]+$/))
    if (!seen[s]) {
        print $0
        seen[s] = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: This one needs an asterisk after the closing square bracket to match the correct substring.  Apart from that, it is identical to `awk '!x[substr($0, 1,16)]++ ' file.csv`.  They both suffer in that they print the first of a set of near duplicates, rather than the last.

Comment: Identical wrt this training data, that is

Comment: Thanks for the correction, and good catch on the OP's requirements

Comment: You can make this work "correctly" by sandwiching it between invocations of `tac`, e.g. `tac | script.awk file.txt | tac`. If you're lucky enough to have tac, of course. :)

Comment: I meant `tac | script.awk | tac file.txt`

Comment: tac file.csv|script.awk | tac

Comment: Nice solution!  Can be combined with Dennis' solution in the case he identified.

Answer (score 1):

As a general strategy (I'm not much of an AWK pro despite taking classes with Aho) you might try:

1. Concatenate all the fields except
   the last.
2. Use this string as a key to a hash.
3. Store the entire line as the value
   to a hash.
4. When you have processed all lines,
   loop through the hash printing out
   the values.

This isn't AWK specific and I can't easily provide any sample code, but this is what I would first try.