# How can I remove selected lines with an awk script?

Tags: sorting, awk, duplicates

I'm piping a program's output through some awk commands, and I'm almost where I need to be.  The command thus far is:

```
myprogram | awk '/chk/ { if ( $12 > $13) printf("%s %d\n", $1, $12 - $13); else  printf("%s %d\n", $1, $13 - $12)  }  ' | awk '!x[$0]++'
```

The last bit is a poor man's `uniq`, which isn't available on my target.  Given the chance the command above produces an output such as this:

```
GR_CB20-chk_2, 0
GR_CB20-chk_2, 3
GR_CB200-chk_2, 0
GR_CB200-chk_2, 1
GR_HB20-chk_2, 0
GR_HB20-chk_2, 6
GR_HB20-chk_2, 0
GR_HB200-chk_2, 0
GR_MID20-chk_2, 0
GR_MID20-chk_2, 3
GR_MID200-chk_2, 0
GR_MID200-chk_2, 2
```

What I'd like to have is this:

```
GR_CB20-chk_2, 3
GR_CB200-chk_2, 1
GR_HB20-chk_2, 6
GR_HB200-chk_2, 0
GR_MID20-chk_2, 3
GR_MID200-chk_2, 2
```

That is, I'd like to print only line that has a maximum value for a given tag (the first 'field').  The above example is representative of the at data in that the output will be sorted (as though it had been piped through a `sort` command).

Comment: If you find yourself squeezed for space and speed and this is not premature optimization, you can replace your `if ... printf ... else ...printf ...` with the shorter and, at least on my system, faster "poor man's `abs()`": printf("%s %d\n", $1, (($12 > $13) * 2 - 1) * ($12 - $13))`

Comment: Also, note that your `awk` command that filters lines on `/chk/` can be combined into my script below (with mods to save the appropriate "prev" fields instead of the whole line, etc.) so you're only calling `awk` once. At the top of my script, `s` would be set to `(($12 > $13) * 2 - 1) * ($12 - $13)` *(untested)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589756/how-to-delete-partial-duplicate-lines-with-awk/1590177#1590177) to a similar need, this script keeps things in order and doesn't accumulate a big array. It prints the line with the highest value from each group.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    s = substr($0, 0, match($0, /,[^,]*$/))
    if (s != prevs) {
        if ( FNR > 1 ) print prevline
        prevval = $2
        prevline = $0
    }
    else if ( $2 > prevval ) {
        prevval = $2
        prevline = $0
    }
    prevs = s
}
END {
    print prevline
}
```

Comment: Much faster, and because memory is a concern (it's an embedded environment) I'm switching to this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the items to be in the same order they were output from myprogram, the following works:

```
... | awk '{ if ($2 > x[$1]) x[$1] = $2 } END { for (k in x) printf "%s %s", k, x[k] }'
```

Comment: Just missing the "\n" in the printf().  Otherwise perfect.

Comment: Ah, right.  I had that in my test version but forget it when typing it here.  :)